# Axiom of Choice Exercise

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

In his book, *Naive Set Theory*, Paul R. Halmos leaves it as an exercise to show how a surjective relation implicitly defines a function using the axiom of choice. I am completely new to the axiom, and find it quite the peculiar. Perhaps, I might have misunderstood it completely (please tell me if I have), but the way I attempted at it is as follows:

if $R$ be a relation between non-empty sets $X$ and $Y$, then it is true that each value of $R$ in $Y$ has a preimage in $X$. We can then form a collection $C$ that consists of all preimages of $R$. Namely, if $a,b,c,d ...$ be elements of $Y$, then $C$ = $\{R\{a\}^{-1}, R\{b\}^{-1}, R\{c\}^{-1}, R\{d\}^{-1} ...\}$. Hence, the cartesian product of $C$ will consist of functions with the range consisting of elements in $X$. So if we choose the range of any of these functions, we can call this the domain of our function $f$ and map each element of $f$ to the element in $Y$ whose preimage it was a part of. Would this be correct? I only seek affirmation and, perhaps, guidance from those more professional. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the idea is that.

Observe it is simpler to confine yourself to *total* relations, that is relations in which every element of the domain has assigned at least one element of the codomain. Why that? Functions are total relations.

---

In general, for every function $f : X \to Y$ you can consider the family of the *fibers* of $f$, that is the sets $$f^{-1}(y) := \{x \in X \mid f(x) = y\} .$$
These sets are pairwise disjoint and cover $X$. However, in general some fibers may be empty. If $f$ is a surjection, the fibers do form a partition of $X$.

Now what? This:

> Assuming the axiom of choice, every surjective function $f : X \to Y$ has one (injective) function $g : Y \to X$ for which $fg = 1_Y$.

Applying the axiom of choice to the family $\{f^{-1}(y) \mid y \in Y\}$, there is a *choice function* $g : Y \to X$, that is $g(y) \in f^{-1}(y)$ for every $y \in Y$.